# Beautiful soup - select all elements that have a class, but also separate them or ignore elements if they have also other clases

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="alpha">
<div class="alpha">
<div class="alpha">
<div class="alpha betha">
<div class="alpha gama">
<div class="alpha">
```

I need to

1. get all the elements that have only 'alpha' as a class in a list.
2. get all elements that have 'alpha' and 'betha'in another list.
3. Ignore other combinations like "alpha gama".

I know I can get all elements that have a class

```
container.findAll('div', {'class': 'alpha'})
```

But how to separate/ignore for 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors with the `.select()` method:

```py
txt = '''<div class="alpha">1</div>
<div class="alpha">2</div>
<div class="alpha">3</div>
<div class="alpha betha">4</div>
<div class="betha alpha">5</div>
<div class="alpha betha gama">6</div>
<div class="alpha gama">7</div>
<div class="alpha">8</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

only_alpha = soup.select('[class="alpha"]')
only_alpha_betha = soup.select('.alpha.betha:not(.gama)')

print('Only alpha:', only_alpha)
print('Only alpha and betha:', only_alpha_betha)
```

Prints:

```
Only alpha: [<div class="alpha">1</div>, <div class="alpha">2</div>, <div class="alpha">3</div>, <div class="alpha">8</div>]
Only alpha and betha: [<div class="alpha betha">4</div>, <div class="betha alpha">5</div>]
```

Comment: Great answer. I have used your html sample in my own answer. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a helper function ?

`bs4`  allows you to specify [`a function as filter`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) while searching the tree with *find_all()*.

From the docs:

> If none of the other matches work for you, define a function that
>   takes an element as its only argument. The function should return `True`
>   if the argument matches, and `False` otherwise.

The issue is that we can't pass any other arguments (A list of valid classes in this case). We can overcome this by using a wrapper function to dynamically create the filters.

```
def create_filter(tag_name, class_list):
    def class_filter(tag):
        return (
            tag.name == tag_name and
            set(tag.get('class', [])) == set(class_list)
        )
    return class_filter
```

Let's see how this works on @AndrejKesely 's sample html.

**Only `alpha`**

```
print(soup.find_all(create_filter('div', ['alpha'])))
```

Output

```
[<div class="alpha">1</div>, <div class="alpha">2</div>, <div class="alpha">3</div>, <div class="alpha">8</div>]
```

**Only `alpha` and `betha`**

```
print(soup.find_all(create_filter('div', ['alpha', 'betha'])))
```

Output

```
[<div class="alpha betha">4</div>, <div class="betha alpha">5</div>]
```